# useState("") or React.useState("")

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```js
import { useState } from "react";
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
```

```js
const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
```

Which one is better to use and why?

I'm looking for which approach is better and why?

Comment: they are the same and no matter which one you use, but useState(0) is more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { useState } from "react";
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

I think this is the better and new approach because we only import the required hook by destructuring, not the whole react library.
This makes code efficient and light.
However, the specific ReactJS library is globally installed.

Answer (score 0):

**They are identical**. Why you'd use one over the other is basic styling preference

Answer (score 0):

They're the same function, you're just importing them differently. In the first example, you imported just useState from React by deconstructing it.

While in the second, you imported the whole react library, thus requiring you to write React.useState.